# Constantly changing list of data in excel with a data validation list

Tags: excel

I have a piece of coding which will order a list of people in order from the highest to the lowest performance (in percent). This means that if a person performs well and the person value goes up, they will then go up the list of people, this coding is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[Filename.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$4:$A$1000,MATCH(LARGE('[Filename.xlsx]Sheet'!$AS$4:$AS$1000,ROW()-4),'[Filename.xlsx]Sheet'!$AS$4:$AS$1000,0)),"")
```

***dragged down***

The coding above works from a piece of coding which ranks data so the higher the data, the higher the number will be:

```
{=IF(AR4="","",SUM(1*(AR4>$AR$4:$AR$1000))+1+IF(ROW(AR4)-ROW($AR$4)=0,0,SUM(1*(AR4=OFFSET($AR$4,0,0,INDEX(ROW(AR4)-ROW($AR$4)+1,1)-1,1)))))}
```

***dragged down***

So the code above pulls through the employees unique ID dependent on their performance percentage.

With the unique ID, I have used VLOOKUPS to get the rest of the data to come through with it, including name, country, sector etc...so if a person performance goes up, they move up the list and the correct data is kept on the same line.

Now the problem I am having is I want to assign manually these people to a job role using a data validation list in a new column that is where the problem begins.

So I have added a column where each cell contains a data validation list so when I give a person a job role...and somebody moves up the list, the rest of the data moves down BUT, the job role/data validation stays in the same cell and does not move down with the data. I was wondering if there is any way to counter this and make it so when a job role is attached to an employee it will move with that employee.

An example of the above:

```
Unique ID    Name    Country    Performance  JOB ROLE    
123456789    tom     UK         90%          BOSS
987868564    bill    USA        76%          SALESMAN
162537456    steve   sweden     52%          WORKER
```

Now, in a case where steve gets 99% performance:

```
Unique ID    Name    Country    Performance  JOB ROLE (List)   
162537456    steve   sweden     99%          BOSS
123456789    tom     UK         90%          SALESMAN
987868564    bill    USA        76%          WORKER
```

Notice the job roles stay in the same place? - Tom should have the BOSS job role, bill should be a salesman and steve should be a worker.

Comment: I don't know whether it be possible or not to improve your question, but I find it hard to read.  Many users will pass over the question because of this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added an example, if this will help

Comment: You must assign the job role in that table where the data really is statically stored. The dynamic table should then get the role with `VLOOKUP` from that table like name and country also.

Comment: @AxelRichter I thought of that but I was wondering whether or not there is a way of attaching the job roles column cell contents to the unique ID as soon as it is changed but that may be a little far-fetched...although I thought the above way of ordering people with the coding above was not possible at one point.

Comment: Of course it would be also possible to assign the job role to the unique id in a third table and get then into the dynamic table from that third table using `VLOOKUP`. But in every case the relation unique Id <-> job role must be statically stored somewhere.

Comment: I never thought of assigning the job role like that, this is the way i will be doing it, I am going to make a clone table which pulls the data across normally and then, as you say, make a vlookup which will bring the job role across, thanks